# Combining two transitions properties in Tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I wanna have `transition-transform` and `transition-shadow`, not neither `transition-all` nor only one. Putting the two not effecting, i couldn't find doc for it, i tried playing around like: `transition-[transform, shadow]` and obviously didn't work.

Basically, i have cards, you hover on it, it scale up a bit and drops a shadow.
`className='hover:scale-105 hover:shadow-2xl transition-transform transition-shadow'`
How to put transition properties `transform` and `shadow` together?

My app has white and black theme, that's way i don't want just to put `transition-all` because it flashes when switching the theme.

Comment: It should be `transition-[transform,shadow]`, i.e. without the space in-between.

Comment: @brc-dd oh yeah it worked. One more question, how can i give different duration for these transition properties?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Only for TailwindCSS v3**

Setting a class like `transition-[transform, shadow]` is interpretted by browsers as two separate classes: `transition-[transform,` and `shadow]`.

You need to remove the space if possible or replace it by an underscore (`_`). That said, in your case you simply need to write:

```
transition-[transform,shadow]
// or
transition-[transform,_shadow]
```

If you want to customize their durations as well you can write something like:

```
[transition:transform_1s,shadow_2s]
```

---

Based on [Adding Custom Styles - TailwindCSS v3](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#handling-whitespace)

> When an arbitrary value needs to contain a space, use an underscore (`_`) instead and Tailwind will automatically convert it to a space at build-time:
>
> ```html
> <div class="grid grid-cols-[1fr_500px_2fr]">
>   <!-- compiled to -- grid-template-columns: 1fr 500px 2fr; -->
> </div>
> ```
>
> In situations where underscores are common but spaces are invalid, Tailwind will preserve the underscore instead of converting it to a space, for example in URLs:
>
> ```html
> <div class="bg-[url('/what_a_rush.png')]">
>   <!-- compiled to -- background-image: url('/what_a_rush.png'); -->
> </div>
> ```
>
> In the rare case that you actually need to use an underscore but it’s ambiguous because a space is valid as well, escape the underscore with a backslash and Tailwind won’t convert it to a space:
>
> ```html
> <div class="before:content-['hello\_world']">
>   <!-- compiled to -- content: var('hello_world'); -->
> </div>
> ```

Comment: I dont think transition-[transform_1s,shadow_2s] works. Tried it on https://play.tailwindcss.com/ and it's interpreted as transition-property:transform 1s,shadow 2s (which is completely wrong)

Comment: @mr1031011 Ah yeah. You need to do: `[transition:transform_1s,shadow_2s]`

Comment: In addition to customizing the duration, can one specify the delay for each transition?

Comment: @greener Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition#syntax -- `[transition:transform_1s_100ms]` (here 1s is the duration, 100ms is the delay)

Answer (score 6):

I needed to do `transition-[transform,box-shadow]` not `shadow`

Answer (score 6):

It is a bit off the question, however since I found this answer while searching for a solution I will give it a try.

To combine 2 transition properties with different durations or timing function, you would need to use Tailwindcss v3 with something like:

```
before:[transition:_color_0.1s,transform_0.2s_ease-out]
```

It answers https://stackoverflow.com/users/16945230/a-anvarbekov problem, I would have commented it but SO requires 50 reps to comment now.

Hope it helps some people out there!