# Is it possible to write an arbitrary Tailwind CSS class that contains whitespace?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

In Tailwind CSS 3.0+ JIT mode is enabled by default and you can write arbitrary CSS properties.

**Example**

```html
<!-- this works -->
<div className="[background:red]"></div>
```

but... if I wanna write some property that contains whitespace.

```html
<!-- this doesn't work -->
<div className="[background:linear-gradient(241deg,#CCF9FF 0%,#DEF7FF4 100%)]"></div>
```

It doesn't work because the whitespace will split this class into multiple classes.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70448374/11613622. Replace space by `_`.